# Is there a way I can Reformat ((((1000*1.08)*1.08)*1.08)*1.06)?

Tags: percentages

I'm trying to increase a value by a percentage multiple times, is there a way I can group together the percentages and multiply 1000 by it

Comment: $1.08^3\cdot1.06\cdot1000$?

Comment: Multiplication is commutative, so effectively, you can multiply by $1000$ last.